# two-way databinding

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

I have a problem with two-way databindig. Here are my classes:

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {
private String name;
private String surname;
private Address address;

public User() {
}

public User(String name, String surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

@Bindable
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.address);
}

@Bindable
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
}

@Bindable
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.surname);
}
}

public class Address extends BaseObservable {
private String name;

public Address(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Bindable
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

I am trying to bind User in xml file, but also i want to bind address name. Unfortunately when I use address.setName("abc") my UI doesn't change. I was using notifyPropertyChanged(BR.address) in address setter but it didn't help. It is possible to do it in that way? Here are snippets of my xml file:

```
    <data>
            <variable name="user" type="com.rolnik.test.User"/>
        </data>

android:text="@={user.name}"
android:text="@={user.surname}"
android:text="@={user.address.name}"
```

Comment: Could you share full code of layout?

Comment: @ConstOrVar here is my xml https://hastebin.com/oluhejiyok.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem. I put notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name) in address setter and rebuild project. Without the last one it doesn't work.